# sbt-native-packager, hook into the debian package lifecycle

Tags: scala, sbt, deb, sbt-native-packager

I try to use sbt-native-packager to build deb package. I want to hook into the debian package lifecycle. I try to achieve this according to instructions on the sbt-native-packager site. In my build.sbt I added sth like:

```
import DebianConstants._
maintainerScripts in Debian := maintainerScriptsAppend((maintainerScripts in Debian).value)(
  Preinst -> "echo 'hello, world'",
  Postinst -> s"echo 'installed ${(packageName in Debian).value}'"
)
```

But I get error `cannot resolve symbol DebianConstants`. I use sbt 0.13.9, scala 2.11.6 and sbt-native-packager 1.0.6. I searched in packages and I can't find anything like `DebianConstants`. I also can't find `maintainerScripts` key for `Debian`. It seems that sbt-native-packager site is out of date. Is there a way to programmatically hook into the debian package lifecycle?

PS I know there is a way to place scripts into `src/debian/DEBIAN`. But I want to know if there is a way to do it in `build.sbt` (just for fun)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use this kind of code in your `build.sbt`, you need the `1.1.0-RC` release version. Just add this to your `project/plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.1.0-RC1")
```